# Is there a significant difference when loading files using forward slash vs backward slash in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slash

I have been writing Node.js apps for quite some time now, and I have been seldom paying any attention to the use of forward slash vs backward slash when loading files using Node.js on Windows.

Now, after using both interchangeably without a problem, I'm starting to wonder, is there a significant difference between the two?

Up until now, the only difference that I have noticed is that JavaScript's string literal (just like C and C++), requires that every backward slash be preceded by another backward slash. (In fact this is why I have been reluctant to use the backward slash, recently -- even for Node.js on Windows --, because I fear forgetting that extra slash.)

Comment: Use `/` always. node normalizes file URI strings to be cross platform for you

Comment: Agree with Raynos.  Using the `\ ` character in file paths as a throwback to ancient days.  Windows has supported `/` in paths since XP.

Comment: @Raynos Node does not do anything. Windows and POSIX are both compliant with forward slashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like what Raynos said in the comments, I should use the forward slash always, even on Windows.

**Update**

The above answer is really, really outdated. Always use [`path.join`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) when constructing file paths from scratch.

Example:

```
// Get file.txt from a folder called `somefolder` that is
// located in the same directory as the currently running
// .js file.
path.join(__dirname, 'somefolder', 'file.txt');
```